# Errors in R studio for loop unable to find solution

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I'm getting errors in R studio with the following code. After searching for days I'm unable to find a solution. Any help is appreciated!

```
for(i in 1:nrow(newData)){

#find the week that it corresponds to
  rowsToReplace = newData$date == unique(cleanMovieData$releaseDate[i])

  #find the rank 1 and rank 2 movie in that week
  releaseWeek1 = cleanMovieData$releaseWeekEarnings [which(cleanMovieData$releaseRank[i] == 1)]
  releaseWeek2 = cleanMovieData$releaseWeekEarnings [which(cleanMovieData$releaseRank[i] == 2)]

  #take the log revenue in those weeks and compare
  logReleaseCompare = log(releaseWeek1) - log(releaseWeek2)

  newData$releaseBoxOfficeDiff[rowsToReplace] = logReleaseCompare
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some reproducible data?  What error are you receiving?

Comment: I get the following output:

Comment: "rror: unexpected input in "  
>   #find the rank 1 and rank 2 movie in that week
>   releaseWeek1 = cleanMovieData$releaseWeekEarnings [which(cleanMovieData$releaseRank[i] == 1)]
"rror: unexpected input in "  releaseWeek1 = cleanMovieData$releaseWeekEarnings [which(cleanMovieData$releaseRank[i] == 1)]
>   releaseWeek2 = cleanMovieData$releaseWeekEarnings [which(cleanMovieData$releaseRank[i] == 2)]
"rror: unexpected input in "  releaseWeek2 = cleanMovieData$releaseWeekEarnings [which(cleanMovieData$releaseRank[i] == 2)]
>